# python search and replace

Tags: python, string, replace

I have a file with string of text containing names which I would like to replace. I have another file with two columns, A and B containing names. Column A contains the same names as in the string (file 1). I would basically like to replace those names with the names in column B. I have tried using Python, but I'm still too much of a beginner to pull it off. Any pointer would be greatly appreciated.

```
File1               
NameA.....NameB....NameC....etc

File2                 
A     B    
NameA NameD         
NameB NameE          
NameC NameF
```

Would like;

```
File1                       
NameD....NameE....NameF....etc
```

Comment: [What have you tried](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com) that doesn't work?

Comment: I should have added that of course. See below.

Answer (score 1):

```
#read filrst file as list
with open("file1") as f:
    names1=f.read().strip().split();

#read file2 as dictionary
with open("file2") as f:  
    names2=dict(i.strip().split() for i in  f.readlines())

#write replacement in file3
with open("file3","w") as f:
    f.write(" ".join(names2[i] for i in names1))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
with open('File1', 'r') as fd:
    keys = fd.read().split()

name_map = {}

with open('File2', 'r') as fd:
    for line in fd.readlines():
        key, value = line.split()
        name_map[key] = value

with open('File1', 'w') as fd:
    new_names = []
    for k in keys:
        new_names.append(name_map[k])
    fd.write(" ".join(new_names))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would consider using RegEx (the re module in Python). This would allow you to create functions that could search for specific text patterns. You could extract select "groups" of text using the group() function if you properly construct your re.compile() function and re.search() function. The library is quite extensive, so here is a link to the documentation:

http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

I would also check out an online tutorial, such as this one:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DRR9fOXkfRE

Answer (score 0):

I think you need code like this:

```
File1 = open("File1", "r")   
File2 = open("File2", "r")   
File3 = open("File3","w")

for line in File2:

    A, B  = line.strip().split('\t')

    for line_string in File1:

        line_string.replace(A,B)

        File3.write('%s\n' % line_string)

File3.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the replies. Although, none didn't really work properly. Probably due to the nature of the string in file1 (newick format). This is what I originally worked on... probably not so good. Although, if I could get a replace function to work it might do the trick..?

```
import re

LineString = open("file1.txt", "r").read()

pattern = re.compile('\d+OTU\_\d+\_\w+\_\d+')
words = pattern.findall(LineString)

colA = []
colB = []

with open("file2.txt", "r") as f:
for line in f:
    parts = line.split()
    if len(parts) > 0:
        colA.append(parts[0])   
    if len(parts) > 1:
        colB.append(parts[1])

#Doesnt work
if words == colA:
LineString.replace(colA, colB)
```

String in file1 one looks like:(((((((((('1OTU_1_769_wint_446':0.00156420,'1OTU_1_822_wint_445':0.00000000)0.5700:0.00156410,'1OTU_1_851_wint_454':0.00000000) etc...

words, colA, colB looks like: e.g. 1OTU_1_769_wint_446

Comment: Combining the RegEx search with the Dictionary example provided from Yarkee worked like a charm. Thanks.

Comment: You should merge this into your question so everyone sees it.